# BIg-F5 and Apache SSL configuration

Tags: apache, ssl, f5

Configure Apache and F5 loadbalancer.

From Apache layer we generate CSR and get the trusted cer as:

1) `.cer`

2) `.p7b`

Then I convert the `.cer` and `.p7b` file to `.crt` file and configure in our apache as keyfile, certificate and chain.

We are facing some issue while configuring the SSL between F5 and Apache. Our flow is:

```
Client(SSL) -> F5 (SSL drops ) -> (recreate ssl to apache layer) -> Apache webserver.
```

1) create CSR from apache web layer, get sign as trusted from the company (not external)

2) configure in `ssl.conf` and `ciphersuite`

Now initiate a request using openssl it is throwing:

```
depth = 1 
DC = net 
DC = racb 
CN = XXXXXX 

CA 1 verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate read from 0x1b9c8d0 [0x1ca04f3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
```

In order to verify it I modified the `/etc/hosts` entry as `xxx.xxx.xxx.net` as `127.0.0.1` and move the chain certificate to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchor` and `update-ca-trust` extract and run the `openssl` which is return with error `code=0` and waiting in SSL session.

What mistake we are doing in F5 no idea.

Can someone throw the lights?

Answer (score -1):

If you're setting up a bridging config, you need both an SSL Client Profile (typically you take your Apache key/cert/chain) and an SSL Server Profile, and both are chosen on the Virtual Server configuration.

For the Client Profile you first need to import the private key, the certificate(s) and of course you have to see on the Certificates screen that the private key matches the certificate.

Usually for the Server Profile, if we know that we can trust the backend server, instead of setting up something with certificates of your own, we just choose the unsecure-compatible profile and it will work in almost all cases.

If there is no need to setup SNI, it's enough to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: if you explain bit more clear what we have do this will be good.

Comment: for More understanding Using Server profile if we disable the client unsecure-compatible profile surely it will work??

Comment: This is the right place for asking help in debugging software, not for asking a lesson on SSL bridging. There are many articles and questions/answers on F5 sites (F5.com , devcentral). To your last question : no.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer